# SwiftUI: Presenting multiple ShareLinks in a menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu

I'd like to present share menu with multiple options. I've created a Menu and added all ShareLink views. I can tap the share button, but if I select a ShareLink, nothing happens. No error message.

This is the only way I can think of to create such a "share menu":

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: SwiftUI.ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {

    Menu {
          ShareLink(
               item: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,
               preview: SharePreview(
                   "Test 123",
                    image: Image(systemName: "plus")
                    )
                )
               ShareLink(
                    item: URL(string: "https://www.microsoft.com")!,
                    preview: SharePreview(
                        "Tests 321",
                         image: Image(systemName: "minus")
                    )
                )

        } label: {
               Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Submit as a bug, maybe it will get fixed before RC. What is likely happening is that  the menu is already presenting where the share sheet wants to present

Comment: This was fixed in iOS 16.1! Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ShareLink` inside a menu doesn't currently work. A Menu is technically a new View Controller (`UIContextMenuActionsOnlyViewController`) presented over the active window. The Share Action Sheet needs a View controller to present from. When a `ShareLink` inside a `Menu` is tapped, it dismisses the menu VC, along with the share action sheet. You can verify this by checking the view hierarchy when a Menu is open.

One workaround is to manually create Button/MenuItem/s and show a share action sheet on button tap from the underlying View; which avoids using ShareLink directly.

Workaround:

```
...
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: SwiftUI.ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {
  Menu {
    Button(action: {
      showShareSheet(url: URL("https://www.apple.com")!)
    }) {
      Label("Share1", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
    }
    Button(action: {
      showShareSheet(url: URL(string: "https://www.microsoft.com")!)
    }) {
      Label("Share2", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
    }
  } label: {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
  }
}
...

// UIActivityViewController can be customised. 
// For examples, see https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example
func showShareSheet(url: URL) {
  let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
  UIApplication.shared.currentUIWindow()?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// utility extension to easily get the window 
public extension UIApplication {
    func currentUIWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        let connectedScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
        
        let window = connectedScenes.first?
            .windows
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }

        return window
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't actually work for me, here are the logs https://pastebin.com/DJPvHS50.
I'm using it inside of UISheetPresentationController, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The clue is on line 4. In your setup, you're presenting from a view controller, that is already presenting another view controller.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed in iOS 16.1! Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve the desired behavior with custom popover bridged from UIKit.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShareSheetView: View {
    @State private var isShowingPopover = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("Hello, world!")
                
                Button("Show Popover") {
                    isShowingPopover = true
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button {
                        isShowingPopover.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }
                    .uiKitPopover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover) {
                        VStack {
                            ShareLink(
                                item: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,
                                preview: SharePreview(
                                    "Test 123",
                                    image: Image(systemName: "plus")
                                )
                            )
                            Divider()
                            ShareLink(
                                item: URL(string: "https://www.microsoft.com")!,
                                preview: SharePreview(
                                    "Tests 321",
                                    image: Image(systemName: "minus")
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        .fixedSize()
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ShareSheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ShareSheetView()
    }
}

struct PopoverViewModifier<PopoverContent>: ViewModifier where PopoverContent: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    let content: () -> PopoverContent
    let permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection = []
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                Popover(
                    isPresented: $isPresented,
                    onDismiss: onDismiss,
                    content: self.content
                )
            )
    }
}

struct Popover<Content: View> : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    let permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection = []
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self, content: self.content())
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.host.rootView = self.content()
        if self.isPresented, uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
            let host = context.coordinator.host
            host.preferredContentSize = host.sizeThatFits(in: CGSize(width: Int.max, height: Int.max))
            host.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
            host.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            host.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = uiViewController.view
            host.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = uiViewController.view.bounds
            host.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = permittedArrowDirections
            uiViewController.present(host, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
        let host: UIHostingController<Content>
        private let parent: Popover
        
        init(parent: Popover, content: Content) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.host = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        }
        
        func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            self.parent.isPresented = false
            if let onDismiss = self.parent.onDismiss {
                onDismiss()
            }
        }
        
        func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
            return .none
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func uiKitPopover<Content>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil, content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content: View {
        self.modifier(PopoverViewModifier(isPresented: isPresented, onDismiss: onDismiss, content: content))
    }
}
```