# SwiftUI open ShareLink from ActionSheet (confirmationDialog) Not Working

Tags: swiftui, share, ios16, actionsheet

I have a ShareLink inside an ActionSheet (confirmationDialog) but it's not opening. Can anyone confirm if this is possible or not? I imagine it's something to do with the action sheet being dismissed at the same time.

```
.confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $isShowingMoreActionSheet, titleVisibility: .hidden) {
        
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
            ShareLink("Share", item: url)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you're right. When the confirmation sheet dismisses, the ShareSheet will also be dismissed. Also why do you want the ShareLink inside of a confirmationDialog?

Comment: Hey, I have a "more" button that opens the action sheet to give the user multiple actions, one of which is to share a link. Seems link a pretty standard feature.

Comment: I guess the sharing via confirmationDialog can be done by using the old actionSheet from UIKit. If you want to use the ShareLink I would recommend using it inside a Menu. See documentation for Menu here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu

Comment: Ooo, interesting! Good shout thanks

Comment: I was looking for another answer when I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73424912/swiftui-presenting-multiple-sharelinks-in-a-menu. Appearently the ShareLink doesn't really work well with being displayed in a Menu or ConfirmationDialog. Maybe Apple will fix this in a newer version, but for now it seems to be impossible. However there is a solution in the StackOverflow Question I sent you in this comment.

Comment: I'm working with iOS 16.1 so it's working now thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon. It's very temperamental. Some times it works fine sometimes it does nothing. It's also all happening in a full screen cover which I think causes more issues

Comment: Actually it does work. What doesn't work is if I have a Menu open and then tap a ShareLink (on the view, not in the menu) it makes the ShareLink unusable

Comment: Actually what you're describing is the same for every buttons. A well known `Menu` bug not yet resolved. And the solution to fix this is really boring!

Answer (score 1):

The Sharelink actually is a button, which is documented in the developer tools:

People tap or click on a share link to present a share interface. The link typically uses a system-standard appearance for the link; you only need to supply the content to share.

Therefore a sharelink is not going to work within an `if let`

Hope this helps!