# SwiftUI: Adding a Share Button to Navigation title menu using ShareLink and the toolbarTitleMenu modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui, share, navigationbar, swiftui-sharelink

If you select a file in the Files app on iOS you can tap on the title and get some extra actions, similar to a context menu. I want this in one of my apps and learned about the `toolbarTitleMenu` modifier. However if I add a `ShareLink` and tap on it, nothing happens.

Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Example Content")
                .toolbarTitleMenu {
                    ShareLink(item: "test share content") // Here, nothing happens
                }
                .navigationTitle("Test Title")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            ShareLink(item: "test share content") // Here it works
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

*iOS 17.2.1*

Comment: Yet another SwiftUI bug. This used to not work, then it got fixed in iOS 16.1, and now it apparently broke again. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73424912/5133585

Comment: Thanks, but that's a different problem that got fixed indeed an still works as expected.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, for now I'm not using the ShareLink in the toolbarTitleMenu modifier. I will file a bug report later. Please upvote.